# Using Blender for design and Cura for slicing; trying to figure out why this is slicing this way

Tags: ultimaker-cura, blender

I am trying to create a test model for a project I am working on and am confused about why this is slicing like this. In Blender, I used the difference boolean to cut a hole in the cylinder on the side of the cube and I deleted the faces of the cylinder and the cube.

I have uploaded the Blender and the .stl files and made them available:

- [Blender file](https://ufile.io/2zxzqctg)
- [STL file](https://ufile.io/ch5ouz3o)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Blender user but the STL file shows a zero wall thickness on the cylinder and no closure to the cylinder. If you close the cylinder, you should be able to test for 3D printable status with a built-in feature of Blender.

Image below is screen capture from Meshmixer user created content:

[image: test stl image]

There's a YouTube video that addresses the 3D print tools, [auto-starting at 8:01](https://youtu.be/-OynHqYd_1I?si=mF_CDqyzdiGk0bii&t=481)

If your objective is to have an open cylinder and cube, it is necessary to offset the walls inward or outward to create thickness. Also ensure that the offset walls are closed.